# PHP: How can I cut the word and add "..."

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I cut the words and add "..." after reaching 4 or 5 words?

The code below states I did the character-based word cuttingb but I need it now to be by word.

Currently I have this kind of code:

```
if(strlen($post->post_title) > 35 )
  {
    $titlep = substr($post->post_title, 0, 35).'...';
  }
    else
  {
    $titlep =  $post->post_title;   
  }
```

and this is the output of title:

```
if ( $params['show_title'] === 'true' ) {
    $title = '<h3 class="wp-posts-carousel-title">';
    $title.= '<a href="' . $post_url . '" title="' . $post->post_title . '">' . $titlep . '</a>';

    $title.= '</h3>';
  }
```

Comment: I suggest using CSS and putting it on the client side, it's a presentation issue: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: Agreed with user2182349. While the pure PHP answers provided below will work, a CSS solution would be more ideal and flexible.

Comment: NAH... it must have " ... " after I cut the 4-5 words.. but thanks anyway to your suggestion. I just need this to be logical.

Comment: you've many answers below. You can accept one of them to mark the question as solved, including your past questions.

Comment: you really shouldn't ignore people. Treating them well is what Stack is about as is being in good standings in a community as such. People won't be so helpful later on having a bad track record such as yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, I'll explode the body and pull out the first x characters.

```
$split = explode(' ', $string);

$new = array_slice ( $split, 0 ,5);

$newstring = implode( ' ', $new) . '...';
```

Just know, this method is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Variant #1

```
function crop_str_word($text, $max_words = 50, $sep = ' ')
{
    $words = split($sep, $text);

    if ( count($words) > $max_words )
    {
        $text = join($sep, array_slice($words, 0, $max_words));
        $text .=' ...';
    }

    return $text;
}
```

Variant #2

```
function crop_str_word($text, $max_words, $append = ' …')
{
       $max_words = $max_words+1;

       $words = explode(' ', $text, $max_words);

       array_pop($words);

       $text = implode(' ', $words) . $append;

       return $text;
}
```

Variant #3

```
function crop_str_word($text, $max_words)
{
    $words = explode(' ',$text);

    if(count($words) > $max_words && $max_words > 0)
    {
        $text = implode(' ',array_slice($words, 0, $max_words)).'...';
    }

    return $text;
}
```

[via](http://api.co.ua/trim-a-string-of-php-on-number-of-words.html)

Comment: credit where credit is due: http://api.co.ua/trim-a-string-of-php-on-number-of-words.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use **str_replace** function of PHP.

```
str_replace('your word', '...', $variable);
```

read that article: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress this functionality is done by `wp_trim_words()` function.

```
<?php
    if(strlen($post->post_title) > 35 )
    {
        $titlep = wp_trim_words( $post->post_title, 35, '...' );
    }
    else
    {
        $titlep =  $post->post_title;   
    }
?>
```

If you do this functionality using PHP then write code as below:

```
<?php
    $titlep = strlen($post->post_title) > 35 ? substr($post->post_title, 0, 35).'...' : $post->post_title;
?>
```